# Cannot view all the output from Windows command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, tree

I entered the following in `cmd`:

```
cd C:/Windows/System32
```

Then I ran the `tree` command.

For some reason, when I scroll up I cannot view the complete command :(

I counted and it only shows the last 298 lines.

Does cmd have some kind of limit or something? Is there any way to view the full command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows Command Prompt *does* have a limit on the characters output to the console window that are saved by the application. The characters that are output to screen are stored in a *buffer* (temporary storage in memory) and its capacity is controlled by setting the **Screen Buffer Size**.

#### Change Screen Buffer Size graphically

The Screen Buffer Size can be increased by carrying out the following steps:

1. Right-click the title bar or click the upper-left corner of the Command Prompt window and select *Properties*.
2. Click the *Layout* tab.
3. In *Screen Buffer Size*, type or select a suitably large number in Height. The max you can enter is 9999. You may also wish to increase the window size.
   [image: Command Prompt properties]
4. Click OK.
5. Close and reopen the terminal for the changes to take effect.

#### Change Screen Buffer Size using commands

You can also change the Screen Buffer Size using old-school DOS commands:

```
mode con:cols=140 lines=32766
```

For more info, see the answers to [How to change Screen buffer size in DOS Command Prompt from batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692673/how-to-change-screen-buffer-size-in-dos-command-prompt-from-batch-script).